# Bash alias not found during start-up on raspberry pi

Tags: python, bash, cron, alias

I am trying to get a simple script to run on start-up of debian Raspberry Pi where
`startupTest.py` writes the time of run to a .txt file

`$python3 /home/pi/startupTest.py` 
runs successfully in command line

`$ python /home/pi/startupTest.py` 
runs successfully in command line

However using
`$ sudo crontab -e`  to write
`@reboot python3 /home/pi/startupTest.py &`

Yields

`bash: alias: python: not found`

`bash: alias: /usr/local/bin/python3.8: not found`

`bash: alias: python: not found`

`bash: alias: /usr/local/bin/python3.8: not found`

`bash: alias: python: not found`

`bash: alias: /usr/local/bin/python3.8: not found`

Okay, am I missing python3.8 in that directory? no

`$ ls /usr/local/bin` shows python3.8

I am a Mechanical Engineering student trying to get a testing system working for my senior design project.

Comment: I'm not sure about under Debian, but for many cron versions the default `PATH` doesn't include /usr/local/bin. Does /usr/bin/python3 and/or /bin/python3 exist? Also, exactly where are you seeing those "bash: alias: ... messages (interactively, in a log, etc)? Try using an explicit path for python (maybe `/usr/local/bin/python3.8` or something like that).

Comment: Have a look here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72644/unable-to-run-reboot-crontab-at-reboot
It might be the case that your environment is not fully loaded when the @reboot command is executed. I am not sure how to work around this safely. There is the option to prepend a sleep to the crontab command. But I'd suggest you to use a systemd unit as well as the linked stackexchange post describes; systemd is running under the hood of crontab anyway (nowadays).

Comment: @GordonDavisson The bash alias messages are shown when I open the command line after start-up.

Comment: @J.Doe Then those are probably from one of your shell init files (probably ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc), not from the cron job. Try `source ~/.bash_profile` and `source ~/.bashrc` and see if you get the same errors. See [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391518/bash-alias-alias-not-found).

Answer (score 2):

The problems is when running `sudo crontab -e` actually that root user runs the script. If in your `startupTest.py` you do not have any special code that might need `sudo` privilege, just remove `sudo` and add your command in `crontab -e` startup  list.

Comment: This worked. Thank You. The folder is populating with the .txt file now